# Android Menu custom Icon

Tags: android, menu

How can I add a custom icon to my android menu the code below is what I currently have in my xml file.

```
 <item android:id="@+id/item1" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" android:title="Blog"></item>
```

the icon is already within my drawable folder

Comment: Please describe your problem if you have one.

Comment: the problem is that I want to reference a custom icon and not a drawable icon from the sdk. How can I reference my custom icon within my xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to replace this in the xml:

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
```

with

```
android:icon="@drawable/your_menu_icon_name"
```

Comment: I have the icon set but I still don't see it in my app :/

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    //Set icon for the menu button
    Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    menu.getItem(0).setIcon(icon);

    return true;
} //End onCreateOptionsMenu()
```

More reading: [MenuItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setIcon%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

Comment: where will this be done in the activity.java or within my xml file?

Answer (score 1):

```
NavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
navView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

This works for me to set the original icon with the original colors.