# Custom android menu icon showing as gray box?

Tags: android

I read [Android Menu custom Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144160/android-menu-custom-icon) but I do have "@drawable/ic_myimage".  Instead of my png, a gray box shows up.  I created the icon set by right clicking res, new android icon set, and browsing to the png on my hard disk.  the pngs show up undeneath my resource resolution folders as "ic_myimage.png".  I created icon sets the same way but with clipart and those show up fine next to this gray box that should be my own png.

Comment: make sure the png appear under drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, and drawable-ldpi

Comment: they appear in hdpi, mdpi and xhdpi, those are the resource resolution folders I referred to.  when i open those pngs in those folders it is  a blank white box though.  I remember it was a blank box in the add android icon set preview too :(

Comment: You could try manually copying them over to the res folder, and make sure they appear properly before you compile

Answer (score 1):

in order to create an icon set, the image/icon you want shown has to have a transparent background.